# How can you define a computed column like this?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I have an `Equipment` table in SQL Server 2008 like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Equipment](
[EquipmentID] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
[EquipmentName] [nchar](50) NOT NULL,
[ProducedDate] [date] NOT NULL,
[WarrantyPeriod] [int] NOT NULL,
[SerialNumber] [nchar](20) NOT NULL,
[BrandID] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Equipment] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
)
```

I want to have a computed column `WarrantyStatus` that will return either `Unexpired` or `Expired` when calculating, based on columns `ProducedDate` and `WarrantyPeriod`.

This is wrong, but it's what I want:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Equipment]
ADD [WarrantyStatus] AS IIF(DATEDIFF(MONTH, [ProducedDate], GETDATE()) < [WarrantyPeriod], "Unexpired", "Expired")
```

Comment: Be careful, this uses the clock on the server which might not be in sync with your web server clocks. Might cause logic glitches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Equipment]
ADD [WarrantyStatus] AS 
case when DATEDIFF(MONTH, [ProducedDate], GETDATE()) < [WarrantyPeriod]
then 'Unexpired'
else 'Expired'
end
```

Comment: Great, I tried that way, but seems I were wrong its syntax. Thank you so much :D